# Multi Languages

Tags: channel

I have a website I am building.  The website needs to be in 7 different languages.  I know that I will need to use a language switcher but I am not sure how I set up the different languages/channels in the admin and/or what is the best approach.  Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it several times using these instructions http://www.sidd3.com/multi-language-website-with-expressionengine/

Answer (score 0):

I use republic variable for that. I dont have 7 languages but i think i can work for you. I'm out of the country for now but as i remember, my index.php redirect to language folder (based on browser's language ) on my root. (fr, en etc..)  i will post my exact set-up next week. I have a post about that on stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Please Do your self a favor... use EEHarbour Transcribe or go with another cms ... every other solution will be a pain.

Transcribe will:

1) create copyes of your entries in any language and link 'em
2) create translations of static text in your templates (without using conditionals in every bit of your code)
3) create translations of template names so for example you have products/watches/mywatch in english and prodotti/orologi/il-mio-orologio in italiano

etc etc...

Expression Engine wasn't done for multilanguage websites but Transcribe is the best way if you have to...

bye
Francesco